# How to start a gRPC server in plain text mode

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I have a microservices architecture with Docker. **Every microservice is both a server and a client.** I'm trying to implement interactive queries on them. I'd like to communicate in plain text.

Server code:

```
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(6666)
        .addService((BindableService) this)
        .build();

server.start();
```

Client code:

```
    // Call the external instance
    final ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder
            .forAddress(hostStoreInfo.getHost(), hostStoreInfo.getPort())
            .usePlaintext()
            .build();
    final InteractiveQueryApiGrpc.InteractiveQueryApiBlockingStub stub = InteractiveQueryApiGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    kafkaComplexMessage = stub.getOrder(request);
    channel.shutdown();
```

Every Docker container is started like this:

```
docker run -p 8080:6666 -p 7070:6666 --env SERVER_PORT=8080 --network mynetwork mymicroservice:latest
```

When the data isn't found in the local state store, I try to access to the correct state store remotely. However, I get this error message:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: http2 exception
(...)
Caused by: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f
```

Of course, each container has a different port, but I logged everything and the right IP and port is called. I have the impression that the server is running with TSL and client in plain text and I'm not sure how to downgrade the server / disable security in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an HTTP/1 proxy between the client and server.

Looking at that error message:

> Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f

`0x485454502f` is "HTTP/" in ASCII. So the client is talking to an HTTP/1 server. gRPC plaintext assumes HTTP/2 ("Starting HTTP/2 with Prior Knowledge" from the HTTP/2 spec) and does not do the HTTP/1→HTTP/2 upgrade.

Easiest solution is if the proxy supports HTTP/2 with prior knowledge, just configure that. If not, you may need to swap to TCP proxy mode, or swap to another proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was being calling the correct IP but with the wrong port due to my inexperience with Docker.

I thought that `docker run -p 8080:6666 (...)` would allow Docker containers to expose ports to other Docker containers, but this is not the case. This is used only to expose ports to the host computer.

For Spring Boot users who want to implement Kafka Interactve Queries:

You may get the IP of the docker container like this:

```
@Value("${spring.cloud.client.ip-address}")
```

and the port is simply the one that is used when the server is started:

```
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(grpcServerPort)
    .addService((BindableService) this)
    .build();
```